# Как поменять целую и дробную часть местами в массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеются дробные числа, такие как: 13.455, 897.547 и т.д.

Нужно поменять числа после запятой на числа до запятой, так: 455.13, 547.897.

[image]

Как сделать?

Создал массив и этим кодом пытался менять местами цифры

Comment: Код текстом приведите в вашем вопросе. Для редактирования нажмите кнопку "Править"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @AlexeyTen А еще `split`, `join` и `map` ) И решение выходит в одну строку

Comment: А код у вас вообще-то запускается? Просто уже на строке  `let Array =/*...*/` вы бы ошибку получили

Comment: @Deonis с чего бы? https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLrCe.png

Comment: А что делать с отрицательными и целыми числами?

Answer (score 1):

Надо уточнить ваш вопрос. В примере у вас не числа, а строки.

Вариант решения для строк:

```js
const arrDouble = ['12.789', '345.897']; // Данные

/** @param {string[]} arr */
const convert = (arr) => arr.map(item => // Меняем массив
    item.split('.') // Каждый элемент делим по разделителю точка
      .reverse() // меняем местами значения
      .join('.') // Собираем значения по разделителю точка
  );

console.log(convert(arrDouble))
```

Код в одну строку выглядит так:

```
const convert = (arr) => arr.map(item => item.split('.').reverse().join('.'));
```

Comment: Какой ад придумался =)
```.replace(/[^.]+/g, "$'$`").slice(1,-1)``` (там не два обратных апострофа, а один, но markdown-у сносит крышу)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а почему бы одной регуляркой не обойтись, без `slice()`  - `'12.789'.replace(/(\d+)\.(\d+)/, '$2.$1')`. Или даже с учетом целый числе - `'12.789'.replace(/(\d+)(\.)(\d+)/, '$3$2$1')`

Comment: @Deonis Так потому и **ад** =)
Так-то первый вариант я написал не приходя в сознание

Comment: @AlexeyTen, разметку в комментарии я поправил, но что-то оно не работает - лишние точки по краям: ```['12.789', '345.897'].map(x => x.replace(/[^.]+/g, "$'$`"))``` - получается `['.789.12.', '.897.345.']`. Update: Тьфу, я slice не скопировал...

Comment: @Deonis, я ещё вот так могу: `['12.789', '345.897'].map(x => x.match(/\d+|\./g).reverse().join(""))`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = ['12.789', '345.897']
console.log(a.map(x => x.replace(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)$/, '$2.$1')))
```